# R how to avoid clusplot interactivity

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I'm using clusplot() function from cluster package, but when the function is called in R Studio it always shows a sort of interactive point locator (that I couldn't figure out still if it is useful at all) with the legend of 'Locator active (Esc to finish)' and a 'Finish' button on the right. However, when I press 'ESC' or press the 'Finish' button the whole script stops and the rest of the script is not executed.

The question is: How to avoid the function to go interactive?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the **manual**!

> labels= 1,
>
> points and ellipses can be identified in the plot (see identify);

You don't want this.

Comment: Hi, thanks!. It would be easier if the word "interactive" is also used in the documentation :)

Comment: That is what I searched for... interactive led me to "identify" and that to this option. Less than 1 minute.